# Ambiguous Method Call Mocking RestTemplate.exchange()

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, mockito

Can't figure out the correct way to use matchers to identify which overload of the exchange method I am targetting. The call I am making:

`restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT, httpEntity, Object.class)`

I've tried using any(Class.class), and a couple other things but nothing is working. There are 2 methods with a similar signature that I am trying to distinguish between:

`exchange(String url, HttpMethod method, @Nullable HttpEntity<?> requestEntity, Class<T> responseType)`

and

`exchange(String var1, HttpMethod var2, @Nullable HttpEntity<?> var3, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> var4)`

Here are my current imports related to Mockito:

```
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

Has anyone been able to mock a call to this method that uses a Class as the 4th parameter instead of a ParameterizedTypeReference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether I misunderstood your question or the issue mentioned by `@MarciejKowalski`, but when running the test from the issue or what I suppose is similar to your example against `mockito-core-2.23.4` / `JDK 1.8.0_151` it works just fine.

[I used JUnit 4 for your example instead of JUnit 5]

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockitoTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        RestTemplate api = Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);
        ResponseEntity<?> response1 = Mockito.mock(ResponseEntity.class);
        ResponseEntity<?> response2 = Mockito.mock(ResponseEntity.class);

        Mockito.when(api.exchange(any(String.class), any(HttpMethod.class), any(HttpEntity.class), any(Class.class))).thenReturn(response1);
        Mockito.when(api.exchange(any(String.class), any(HttpMethod.class), any(HttpEntity.class), any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class))).thenReturn(response2);

        ParameterizedTypeReference mock = Mockito.mock(ParameterizedTypeReference.class);

        Assert.assertEquals(response1, api.exchange("", HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity(""), String.class));
        Assert.assertEquals(response2, api.exchange("", HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity(""), mock));
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved my issue. I copied your test into one of my test classes and ran it successfully. However, When I remove the class type from any of the first 3 any() matchers it fails. Not having explicit class type parameters for each call to any() seems to have been the root of my issue.

Comment: If you deal with overloaded methods always use the any with specificing the parameter type. In case you do not do that `mockito` is unable to identify the matching method signature.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are using the `when().then()` pattern.

Try the `doReturn().when()` approach with your matchers.

Just make sure you use matchers even for the params that you expect directly (use eq() for this).

Here is the issue and fix on [project issue tracker](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1496).

Comment: While the issue you mentioned is still open, when trying it out with some newer versions of mockito there doesn't seem to be an error (anymore?).