# java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<1> but was:<30> in Junit

Tags: junit, mockito

I am new for Junit and Mockito and i am trying to test below code but ia m getting exception --->**java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<1> but was:<30>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:645)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:631)
    at** can some one help me what is mistack?and suggest me right way

### Original

```
public List<GithubModel> getGitHubUsersList(){
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        HttpEntity<GithubModel>httpEntity = new HttpEntity<GithubModel>(httpHeaders);
        ResponseEntity<List<GithubModel>>usersList = restTemplate.exchange("https://api.github.com/repos/git/git/contributors",
                HttpMethod.GET,httpEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<GithubModel>>() {
                });
        return usersList.getBody();
    }
```

### TestCase:

```
    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    MicroServicesTest1 microServicesTest1;

    @Mock
    RestTemplate mockRestTemplate;

    @Before
    public void create(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void getGitHubUsersListTest(){

        ResponseEntity<List<GithubModel>> response = Mockito.mock(ResponseEntity.class);
    Mockito.when(mockRestTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class),
            Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class), Mockito.eq(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<GithubModel>>(){}))).thenReturn(response);
    Mockito.when(response.getBody()).thenReturn(getUsersList());
    List<GithubModel> mocklist = microServicesTest1.getGitHubUsersList();
    assertEquals(1, mocklist.size());
    }

    /**
     * getUsersList
     * @return
     */
    public List<GithubModel>getUsersList(){
        GithubModel githubModel = new GithubModel();
        githubModel.setId(1);
        githubModel.setLogin("hello1");
        githubModel.setNode_id("hello2");
        List<GithubModel>list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(githubModel);
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: You're last parameter is not matching. Check my [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57365466) here. It should be `any( ParameterizedTypeReference.class)` instead of `Mockito.eq(GithubModel.class)`.

Comment: which line your trying to say?

Comment: I edited my code but still its showing same error

Comment: @second you have any idea my code is very clear i think but why this is happening?

Comment: How is `RestTemplate` injected into `MicroServicesTest1`? If its by [`FieldInjection`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) rename your Mock to match the field name: `restTemplate`. -- Also I don't think its a good idea to combine `@Spy` & `@InjectMocks`, but that isn't a problem. Check this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38573651/11514534) for more details about that.

Comment: i followed this link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mock-rest-template

Comment: Plese suggest me with some code because i am learner